# FireBird, udf переделка с архитектуры x32 на х64

Tags: delphi, firebird, interbase

Есть udf, которая записывает файл в blob поле, но она **работает** хорошо на архитектуре *x32*, но у меня *Firebird x64*

Вот этот кусок

```
type

  PInteger  = ^integer;
  PInt      = ^integer;
//  Short     = SmallInt;// 16 bit signed
Short     = LongInt;                                            //МОЯ ПРАВКА
  UShort    = Word;    // 16 bit unsigned
  Long      = LongInt; // 32 bit signed

  TISC_BlobGetSegment = function(BlobHandle: pointer;
                                 Buffer: PChar;
                                 BufferSize: ushort;
                                  var ResultLength: ushort): Short; cdecl;
  TISC_BlobPutSegment = procedure(BlobHandle: pointer;
                                  //Buffer: PChar;
                                Buffer: PAnsiChar; //МОЯ ПРАВКА
                                  BufferLength: Short); cdecl;
  TBlob = record
    GetSegment         : TISC_BlobGetSegment;
    Handle             : pointer;
    SegmentCount       : Long;
    MaxSegmentLength   : Long;
    TotalSize          : Long;
    PutSegment         : TISC_BlobPutSegment;
  end;

  PBlob = ^TBlob;

procedure LoadBLOBFromFile(FileName: PChar;
                           var BLOb: TBLOb); cdecl; export;
// file -> blob
const
  MaxBufSize = 8192;
var
  BufSize, ReadLength, StreamSize: Integer;
//  Buffer: PChar;
Buffer: PAnsiChar;            //МОЯ ПРАВКА
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  try
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      StreamSize := Stream.Size;

      if StreamSize > MaxBufSize then
        BufSize := MaxBufSize
      else
        BufSize := StreamSize;
      GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);
      try
        while StreamSize <> 0 do
          begin
            if StreamSize > BufSize then
              ReadLength := BufSize
            else
              ReadLength := StreamSize;
            Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer^, ReadLength);

           with BLOb do PutSegment(Handle, Buffer, ReadLength);
        {
              Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
              Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Buffer);
              Form1.Show;
          }

            Dec(StreamSize, ReadLength);
          end;
      finally
        FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
      end;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    // do nothing or write error info into initialized log
  end;
end;

exports
 LoadBLOBFromFile;

begin
  isMultiThread:=True;
end.
```

Когда я его проверяю в Delphi, т.е. вывожу «*Buffer*» в «*Memo1*» *dll* работает.
Но как только подходит к непосредственной записи в blob (в самой БД):

```
with BLOb do PutSegment(Handle, Buffer, ReadLength);
```

строкой

```
update SERVICES_TABLE
set field9=LoadBLOBFromFile('d:\1.txt')
where DESCRIPTION = 'temporal holding proposal'
```

значек (квадратика с точками) в поле *blob’а* в базе появляется, но сам *blob* **пустой** (**size: 0 bytes**).
Я знаю что размер данных в разных архитектурах отличаются.

В чем может быть причина?

**Дополнение для знатоков C/C++**

[Заголовочный файл с базовыми типами](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/src/include/types_pub.h)

[Заголовочный файл со структурами для UDF](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/src/jrd/ibase.h)

Вот объявление структуры, которая перенесена в Delphi как TBlob

```
typedef struct blobcallback {
    short (*blob_get_segment) (void* hnd, ISC_UCHAR* buffer, ISC_USHORT buf_size, ISC_USHORT* result_len);
    void*       blob_handle;
    ISC_LONG    blob_number_segments;
    ISC_LONG    blob_max_segment;
    ISC_LONG    blob_total_length;
    void (*blob_put_segment) (void* hnd, const ISC_UCHAR* buffer, ISC_USHORT buf_size);
    ISC_LONG (*blob_lseek) (void* hnd, ISC_USHORT mode, ISC_LONG offset);
} *BLOBCALLBACK;
```

Comment: Что это: `Short     = LongInt; `??? Какой разрядности дельфийская программа?  Покажите С-шное объявление`TISC_BlobPutSegment`.

Comment: Глядишь, так с Вами сам научусь писать UDF

Comment: @MBo, все что было это файл самой скомпелированной библиотеки '*dll' https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsiyvth838lu15i/blobsaveload.dll?dl=0 '' проекта '*.dpr' https://www.dropbox.com/s/278yvixd0ro0txf/blobsaveload.dpr.txt?dl=0 и файла для объявлений в самой БД https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ua7i7pflpckiej/blobsaveload.sql?dl=0

Comment: @MBo, все скомпилировал под х64

Comment: @Konstantin78, поделитесь секретом. Мне это тоже предстоит

Comment: так, подскажите пожалуйста, можно подправить, или без влезания в **TISC_BlobPutSegment** ничего пока сделать нельзя?